# How to block thread on getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two web services calls I need to make from my JQuery 1.9.1 app. I need the results from the first one before I make the second call.

It appears that my getJSON requests do not block the thread. I'm told that javascript is not multi-threaded, so how do I block between these server calls?

Comment: Don't. Put the second call in the first call's callback function.

Comment: Be aware, that the browser will block as well, if you block the JavaScript thread (unless using workers, e.g.)!

Comment: Or, even better (if possible) create a server proxy that combines the calls and then call this proxy. Then you're making the one trip rather than two.

Comment: Since JavaScript is **not** multithreaded, you can't block the *single* thread without blocking your whole app!

Comment: @Bergi - He isn't talking about threads, he's talking about asynchronous requests to the server. each of which will execute some code upon completion, thus fully allowing a race condition in JS.  In that sense, they act very much like threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't need to block threads, that's old school.

You have two options:

- Make the ajax call syncronous.
- Cascade the ajax calls, so the second is made only once the first one is completed.

I recommend the second approach, because that is the *right* way to do it.

```
/* Call 1 */
$.ajax({
    url: 'first url to call',
    data: 'first data sent to the server',
    success: function (results1){

        // Do something with the results    

        /* make the second call */
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sencond url to call'
            data: 'second data sent to the server'
            success: function(results2){

                // Do something when all completed
            }                
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `ajax` functions all return a [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) that implement the [Promise interface](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

Instead of blocking an asynchronous request (and everything else), nest your requests like so

```
$.ajax({...})
    .done(function( data ) {
        // second request
        $.ajax({...});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your 1st ajax request in ***async false*** mode to server

```
$.ajax({
url: Url,
dataType: 'json',
async: false,
 data: myData,
 success: function(data) {
  //stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: That's a hillarious option to add to an AJAX function... the first "A" in AJAX stands for "asynchronous". :)

Comment: Even this answer the question, don't do that

Comment: @roasted - it answers the question in a way.  It could use a little expansion to show how to get the data from the first call into a second call.  +1 anyway.